# Cannot get jQuery intellisense to work in Visual Studio 2010 Professional

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I erased the old 1.4.1 files from my solution, double-checked that no other jQuery packages existed, and then ran `install-package jQuery` from the console.  Three files were downloaded:

jquery-1.6.4.js
jquery-1.6.4.min.js
jquery-1.6.4-vsdoc.js

I rebuilt my solution, and it executed without exceptions being thrown.

I go to write some jQuery in one of my views, and intellisense does not work.

Is there something else I need to do?  Do I need to manually make VS 'see' the vsdoc file?

EDIT 2: Got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that you could include this in the page where you're attempting to access the intellisense:

```
@if (false) {  
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
}
```

You can find further examples of wiring up jquery intellisense in [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523338/jquery-intellisense-vs2010-mvc3).

Answer (score 2):

Create a reference path in the js doc

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.6.5-vsdoc.js" />
```

OR

In your solution, take the vsdoc and literally drag it into your javascript source that you're working on, it will then work. There may be another way to get it to work for all your js docs, but that's how I have done it before.

Once you drag the vsdoc into the js doc, you will see the reference

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.6.5-vsdoc.js" />
```

[Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx) is an alternative source